# RTABMap Ground Plain Off

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've having problems getting the ground plan on rtabmap to show correctly. The pic below shows the ground plan beneath the grid floor. How can I correct this please. I've tried some static transforms but they haven't worked.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rng8qk9c8kemln/Capture.PNG?dl=0

[image: image description]

Incorrect Camera Optical Frame??

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgminqnsig67a05/TF%20Camera%20Optical%20Frame.PNG?dl=0

Full TF tree:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8en0mc5wvlus1s/TF%20Tree.PNG?dl=0

RTABMap Startup Parameters

```
PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/approx_sync: False
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/approx_sync_max_interval: 0.0
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/config_path:
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/expected_update_rate: 0.0
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/frame_id: camera_link
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/ground_truth_base_frame_id:
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/ground_truth_frame_id:
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/guess_frame_id:
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/guess_min_rotation: 0.0
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/guess_min_translation: 0.0
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/keep_color: False
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/max_update_rate: 0.0
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/odom_frame_id: odom
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/publish_tf: True
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/queue_size: 10
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/subscribe_rgbd: False
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/wait_for_transform_duration: 0.2
 * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/wait_imu_to_init: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/Mem/IncrementalMemory: true
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/Mem/InitWMWithAllNodes: false
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/approx_sync: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/config_path:
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/database_path: ~/.ros/rtabmap.db
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/frame_id: camera_link
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/gen_depth: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/gen_depth_decimation: 1
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/gen_depth_fill_holes_error: 0.1
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/gen_depth_fill_holes_size: 0
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/gen_depth_fill_iterations: 1
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/gen_scan: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/ground_truth_base_frame_id:
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/ground_truth_frame_id:
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/initial_pose:
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/landmark_angular_variance: 9999.0
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/landmark_linear_variance: 0.0001
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/map_frame_id: map
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/odom_frame_id:
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/odom_frame_id_init:
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/odom_sensor_sync: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/odom_tf_angular_variance: 0.001
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/odom_tf_linear_variance: 0.001
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/publish_tf: True
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/queue_size: 10
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/scan_cloud_max_points: 0
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_depth: True
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_odom_info: True
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_rgb: True
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_rgbd: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_scan: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_scan_cloud: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_scan_descriptor: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_stereo: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_user_data: False
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/wait_for_transform_duration: 0.2
```

Realsense Startup Parameters

```
PARAMETERS
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/accel_fps: 250
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/accel_frame_id: camera_accel_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/accel_optical_frame_id: camera_accel_opti...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/align_depth: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_color_frame_id: camera_aligned_de...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_fisheye1_frame_id: camera_aligned_de...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_fisheye2_frame_id: camera_aligned_de...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_fisheye_frame_id: camera_aligned_de...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_infra1_frame_id: camera_aligned_de...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_infra2_frame_id: camera_aligned_de...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/allow_no_texture_points: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/base_frame_id: camera_link*
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/calib_odom_file:
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/clip_distance: -1.0
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_fps: 15
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_frame_id: camera_color_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_optical_frame_id: camera_color_opti...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/confidence_fps: 30
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/confidence_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/confidence_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_fps: 15
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_frame_id: camera_depth_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_optical_frame_id: camera_depth_opti...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/device_type:
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_accel: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_color: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_confidence: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_depth: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_fisheye1: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_fisheye2: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_fisheye: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_gyro: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_infra1: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_infra2: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_infra: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_pointcloud: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_pose: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_sync: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/filters:
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye1_frame_id: camera_fisheye1_f...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye1_optical_frame_id: camera_fisheye1_o...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye2_frame_id: camera_fisheye2_f...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye2_optical_frame_id: camera_fisheye2_o...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye_fps: 15
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye_frame_id: camera_fisheye_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye_optical_frame_id: camera_fisheye_op...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/gyro_fps: 400
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/gyro_frame_id: camera_gyro_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/gyro_optical_frame_id: camera_gyro_optic...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/imu_optical_frame_id: camera_imu_optica...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra1_frame_id: camera_infra1_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra1_optical_frame_id: camera_infra1_opt...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra2_frame_id: camera_infra2_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra2_optical_frame_id: camera_infra2_opt...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra_fps: 15
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra_rgb: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/initial_reset: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/json_file_path:
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/linear_accel_cov: 0.01
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/odom_frame_id: camera_odom_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/ordered_pc: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/pointcloud_texture_index: 0
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/pointcloud_texture_stream: RS2_STREAM_COLOR
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/pose_frame_id: camera_pose_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/pose_optical_frame_id: camera_pose_optic...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/publish_odom_tf: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/publish_tf: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/reconnect_timeout: 6.0
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/rosbag_filename:
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/serial_no:
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/stereo_module/exposure/1: 7500
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/stereo_module/exposure/2: 1
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/stereo_module/gain/1: 16
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/stereo_module/gain/2: 16
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/tf_publish_rate: 0.0
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/topic_odom_in: camera/odom_in
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/unite_imu_method: none
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/usb_port_id:
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/wait_for_device_timeout: -1.0
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0
```

Cheers

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413587/rtabmap-ground-plain-off/) by [MarkRobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/142445/markrobotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2023-03-22**:
You may not enough karma to upload an image, can you add a link to image uploaded somewhere else?

**Comment by [MarkRobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/142445/markrobotics/) on 2023-03-24**:
Thanks - I've added a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When the bottom of the point cloud doesn't align with the XY map plane, it means either rtabmap is not using the base frame of your robot, or the Z value of TF between base frame and camera frame is wrong.

Is this used on a robot? Set rtabmap's `frame_id` to `base_footprint` or `base_link` (the base frame of your robot directly on the floor) if it is not already done. If the base frame is already the right one, adjust TF or URDF between the base frame of the robot and the camera base frame.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2023-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkRobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/142445/markrobotics/) on 2023-03-26**:
Hi Thanks for this - I've updated the question with more information re: your comments here. At the moment the camera isn't connected to the robot. Well not in the TF sense. Just realsense and rtabmap running.

I was looking at the camera_*_optical_frame - which might be the cause - though I'm not sure why given I'm using the scripts out of the box without any modification to try and understand where this problem is coming from. I've added a screen shot of this too.

Thanks

Mark

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2023-03-27**:
In TF tree, the base frame is `camera_frame`, so it is normal that half of the image is below the XY plane. When you will be on a robot, you may have a frame `base_link`->`camera_frame` with z=0.5 meters for example, which will make the bottom of the cloud matching the XY plane if rtabmap is using `base_link`. You can simulate this with only the camera, by publishing:
`rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 base_link camera_link 100`
then set `frame_id` of rtabmap to `base_link` instead of `camera_link`.

**Comment by [MarkRobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/142445/markrobotics/) on 2023-03-27**:
Thanks - That's done the job. Thanks for your help